# How to access Password Protected Shared folder through PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

How to access password protected network share folders through PowerBuilder code?
Is there any optios?

I'm using PowerBuilder 11.5

Thanks
Ambat

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippit I had squirrelled away.  I'm not sure of the source so I can't give proper credit.

```
FUNCTION long ShellExecuteW &
    (long hwnd, string lpOperation, &
    string lpFile, string lpParameters,  string lpDirectory, &
    integer nShowCmd ) LIBRARY "shell32"

    string ls_Null
long   ll_rc

SetNull(ls_Null)
ll_rc = ShellExecuteW &
( handle( this ), "open", as_path, ls_Null, ls_Null, 1)

RETURN ll_rc


How about run("net use ...")
where net use syntax is :

NET USE [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

__________________________________________________________________      
DWORD WNetCancelConnection2(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpName,  (string)
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,  (ulong)
  _In_  BOOL fForce
);

DWORD dwResult;
dwResult = WNetCancelConnection2("z:", 
    CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, // remove connection from profile (use 1)
    FALSE);                 // fail if open files or jobs 

DWORD WNetUseConnection(
  _In_     HWND hwndOwner,
  _In_     LPNETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
  _In_     LPCTSTR lpPassword,
  _In_     LPCTSTR lpUserID,
  _In_     DWORD dwFlags,
  _Out_    LPTSTR lpAccessName,
  _Inout_  LPDWORD lpBufferSize,
  _Out_    LPDWORD lpResult
);

Function Declaration:

FUNCTION ulong WNetUseConnectionA (ulong hwndOwner, &
   REF s_netresource lpNetResource, string lpPassword, 
   string lpUsername, ulong dwFlags, REF string lpAccessName, &
   REF ulong lpBufferSize, REF ulong lpResult) library "mpr.dll"
Structure Definition:

$PBExportHeader$s_netresource.srs
global type s_netresource from structure
 unsignedlong  dwScope
 unsignedlong  dwType
 unsignedlong  dwDisplayType
 unsignedlong  dwUsage
 string  lpLocalName
 string  lpRemoteName
 string  lpComment
 string  lpProvider
end type
Mapping Code:

CONSTANT ulong NO_ERROR = 0
CONSTANT ulong CONNECT_REDIRECT = 128
CONSTANT ulong RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 1

s_netresource lstr_netresource

String   ls_null
String   ls_buffer
String   ls_MappedDrive

uLong    ll_bufferlen
uLong    ll_null
uLong    ll_ErrInfo
uLong    ll_success

SetNull(ll_null)
SetNull(ls_null)

ls_buffer = Space(32)
ll_bufferlen = Len(ls_buffer)

lstr_netresource.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
lstr_netresource.lpLocalName = ls_null
lstr_netresource.lpRemoteName = "UNC resource name here"
lstr_netresource.lpProvider = ls_null

ll_ErrInfo = WNetUseConnectionA(ll_null, lstr_netresource, &
   'password', 'username', &
   CONNECT_REDIRECT, ls_buffer, ll_bufferlen, ll_success)

IF ll_ErrInfo = NO_ERROR THEN
   MessageBox("Drive Mapped", "Drive Letter is " + ls_buffer)
   Return 1
ELSE
   MessageBox("Mapping Falied", "Error is " + String(ll_ErrInfo))
   Return -1
END IF      



-------------------- disconnect drive
DWORD WNetCancelConnection2(
  _In_  LPCTSTR lpName,
  _In_  DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_  BOOL fForce
);

DWORD dwResult;
dwResult = WNetCancelConnection2("z:", 
    CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, // remove connection from profile (use 1)
    FALSE);                 // fail if open files or jobs
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Above given solutions are already tried. From these thing only the net use command works. But sometime it doesn't work. Is there any permenent solution for this.